# Wait for processes in c

Tags: c

I was wondering why in my code wait() doesn't seem to work. The program creates two child processes, each one will make two sums of numbers and write the result to a binary file, then, after each process has ended, the parent should read those two results and print them. Even though I use the wait method to make sure each process has ended, the parent process reads the results as zero meaning that the childs haven't written the file yet.
Do you know why this is happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>


double sumaTipo(int size, int inicio, int incremento) {
double suma = 0;
    for (double i = inicio; i < size; i += incremento) {
        suma += tan(sqrt(i));
    }
    return suma;
}

double sumaImpares(int size) {
    return sumaTipo(size, 1, 2);
}

double sumaPares(int size) {
    return sumaTipo(size, 0, 2);
}

double sumaTotal(int size) {
    return sumaTipo(size, 0, 1);
}




int main () {
    
    FILE *ptrW, *ptrR;
    int par1, par2;
    const int SIZE = 50000000;

    if ((ptrW = fopen("fichero.bin", "wb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error en fopen\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    

    if ((par1 = fork()) == -1) {
        printf("Error en fork\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (par1 == 0) {
        if ((par2 = fork()) == -1) {
            printf("Error en el fork\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        if (par2 == 0){ //Padre
            wait(NULL);
            wait(NULL);
            fclose(ptrW);
            printf("Hijos acabados\n");
            if ((ptrR = fopen("fichero.bin", "rw")) == NULL) {
                printf("Error en fopen\n");
                exit(0);
            }
            double result[2];
            fread(result, sizeof(double), 2, ptrR);
            printf("Resultado: %lf, %lf\n", result[0], result[1]);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        } else {    // Hijo 2
            double suma = sumaPares(SIZE); //this is the second result
            fwrite(&suma, sizeof(double), 1, ptrW);
            printf("Hijo 2 acabado: %lf\n", suma);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

    } else {    // Hijo 1
        double suma = sumaImpares(SIZE); //this is the first result
        fwrite(&suma, sizeof(double), 1, ptrW);
        printf("Hijo 1 acabado: %lf\n", suma);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }


}
```

Comment: You might check out "pthread" and "mutex".

Comment: `C` does not have any idea about processes and the function `wait`. Add sufficient information about the OS you are using.

Comment: wait is being placed one after the other without distinction of which process is belongs to, maybe better to separate both processes 1 and 2 into procedures only running their own code with the one wait directive, regardless if the code is basically identical e.g. all inside procedure proc1() and all the other in proc2()

Comment: "rw" is not a valid mode for `fopen()` in standard C or POSIX...

Answer (score 1):

You misread the docs. [fork()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) returns zero to the new *child* process. The *parent* gets a non-zero value: the PID of the new child.